# Why do I keep getting this error when checking a variable within an "if" condition?

Tags: python

When I run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import strftime

#welcome

state = input("Morning? [y/n] ")
if state == y:
    print("Good morning sir! Welcome to our system!")
    pass
else:
    print("Good afternoon sir! Welcome to our system!")
    pass


user = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello World.")
print("{} is using this computer right now".format(user))
print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

I get this error:

```
Morning? [y/n] y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/toshiba/py/hello/hello_world.py", line 7, in <module>
    if state == y:
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

This code is intended to display a custom print message depending on the input of the user as seen in the first input method. I code in python 3 and I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Read the error message and check your code... Something's wrong on line 7!

Answer (score 4):

Your if statement should be:

```
if state == 'y':
```

The type of `state` is a string.

Also, your if statement will currently fail if the user enters `Y` or `yes`. It's not excruciatingly important now, but you could always handle that like this:

```
if state in ('y', 'Y', 'yes'):
```

It's just something good to know for the future.